# ConTeXt standalone on Alpine

Tags: installing, context

There seem to be some issues [installing ConTeXt Standalone](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Standalone) on [Alpine](https://alpinelinux.org/).  Here's a Dockerfile for reproducibility.

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine3.7
RUN apk --no-cache add libc6-compat rsync
RUN mkdir /context && cd /context \
  && wget http://minimals.contextgarden.net/setup/first-setup.sh \
  && sh ./first-setup.sh --modules=all --engine=luatex
```

This fails, and the cause of the error can be seen with `ldd`:

```
/context/bin # ldd luatex
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7fd05109c000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7fd05109c000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7fd05109c000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7fd05109c000)
Error loading shared library ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:
    No such file or directory (needed by luatex)
Error relocating luatex: __rawmemchr: symbol not found
Error relocating luatex: __isnan: symbol not found
```

Alpine uses [musl](https://www.musl-libc.org/), which seems to not work against this build of `luatex`.

Has anyone gotten ConTeXt standalone working on Alpine?

Comment: Currently, you have to compile the binaries yourself and replace them after you downloaded ConTeXt.  I'm actually working on getting musl support into ConTeXt standalone.  TeXlive 2018 *will* have musl support (https://tug.org/texlive/pretest.html scroll all the way down to Platforms).

Comment: Also, crosspost on the mailing list: https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2018/091226.html

Comment: Do you want to self-answer your question, now that musl support has arrived?

Comment: @HenriMenke Please feel free if you wish, but I'm happy to as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Henri Menke noted in the comments, this has been fixed and ConTeXt standalone is now installable on Alpine Linux.